# How to execute function in injected javascript code

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I want to get some data and passed to the website.

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var num = Math.round(10000*Math.random());
        var callbackMethodName = "cb_" + num;

        window[callbackMethodName] = function(data){
            letStart(data);
        }
        var sc = document.createElement("script");
        sc.id = "script_" + callbackMethodName;
        sc.src = "http://example.com/getData.php?callback=" + callbackMethodName;
        document.body.appendChild(sc);      
        document.getElementById(sc.id).remove();        

        function letStart(badges){

            for (var i = 0; i < badges.length; i++){
                console.log(badges[i][0]);
            }

        }

    }
```

If the above code is execute on html page it will work. But when inject the code I get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cb_4276
```

Maybe this part dosent work, but how to make it work?

```
window[callbackMethodName] = function(data){
                letStart(data);
            }
```

// Edit

[Tutorial](http://newtechinfo.net/jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax/)

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle? I would pinpoint the source of the error at the `window[callbackMethodName]` line or the `sc.src` line.

Comment: What line of code does that error point to? Side note you do not need `document.getElementById(sc.id)` you already have a reference to the script element: `sc`, just do `sc.remove()`

Comment: I can't get it work there, but copy the javascript code and replace the src and inside put echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($someArray).")";

Comment: Thats all it shows: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cb_4276
(anonymous function)getData.php:1

Comment: In stand alone file it works, but in the extension it doesnt.